# send smtp mail including html to gmail account

Tags: c#, .net, gmail

I've found this small code that sends email to gmail users. I'd like the body of the mail to contain html (for example, decoding a link for it to hold different text than the url it's pointing to).

I am using c# .net 3.5. I've used these classes in my code:

- MailMessage
- SmtpClient

How can this be done?

Here's a copy of my code:

```
            MailMessage message = new MailMessage("me@gmail.com", WebCommon.UserEmail, "Test", context.Server.HtmlEncode("<html> <body> <a href='www.cnn.com'> test </a> </body> </html> "));
            System.Net.NetworkCredential cred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("him@gmail.com", "myPwd");
            message.IsBodyHtml = true;

            System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");

            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.Credentials = cred;
            smtp.Port = 587;

            smtp.Send(message);
```

Thanks!

Comment: What language/platform/framework at least would be a help, kind of impossible to answer without any details.

Comment: Please post the code you have completed and an example of what you are trying to accomplish. In general you should just need to pass the HTML, it is up to the receiving side to decide what to do with it. You might need to set a header, but without seeing your code I cant say.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this should work:

Note that `MailMessage` refers to `System.Net.MailMessage`. There is also `System.Web.MailMessage`, which I have never used and -as far as I know- is obsolete.

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
// Very basic html. HTML should always be valid, otherwise you go to spam
message.Body = "<html><body><p>test</p></body></html>"; 
// QuotedPrintable encoding is the default, but will often lead to trouble, 
// so you should set something meaningful here. Could also be ASCII or some ISO
message.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
message.IsBodyHtml = true;
// No Subject usually goes to spam, too
message.Subject = "Some Subject";
// Note that you can add multiple recipients, bcc, cc rec., etc. Using the 
// address-only syntax, i.e. w/o a readable name saves you from some issues
message.To.Add("someone@gmail.com");

// SmtpHost, -Port, -User, -Password must be a valid account you can use to 
// send messages. Note that it is very often required that the account you
// use also has the specified sender address associated! 
// If you configure the Smtp yourself, you can change that of course
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(SmtpHost, SmtpPort) {
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(SmtpUser, SmtpPassword),
            EnableSsl = enableSsl;
        };

        try {
            // It might be necessary to enforce a specific sender address, see above
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ForceSenderAddress)) {
                message.From = new MailAddress(ForceSenderAddress);
            }
            client.Send(message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            return false;
        }
```

For more sophisticated templating solutions that render the Body html rather than hard-codin it, there is, for example, the `EMailTemplateService` in MvcContrib which you can use as a guideline.

Comment: ok, I am not sure why my code didn't work before. I copied your code here and it works great, thank you!

Comment: @AaronPatten: May I suggest you formulate that as a new question? Reviving a 5-year-old thread is often not so promising because things change quite a bit over time, and only very few people will get notified... Also, "doesn't render in outlook" isn't very precise - what does it look like, exactly, what are the headers that outlook shows, can you save/upload the .eml file, in what environment does yout code run, etc. would be points your question should address (not here, in a new question).

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it is to create an alternate html view of the email:

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
message.Body = //plain-text version of message
//set up message...

//create html view
string htmlBody = "<html>...</html>";
htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(htmlBody, null, "text/html");
message.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);

//send message
smtpClient.Send(message);
```